# Kernel Timer Precision Test fails with Ubuntu 20.04 on my setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-20.04

**There are several tests that asserts kernel timer precision in linux-test-project**

https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp

- poll02
- pselect01
- pselect01_64
- epoll_wait02
- nanosleep01
- select04
- futex_wait05
- clock_nanosleep02

These tests fails in Ubuntu 20.04 machine with 5.11, 5.12 and 5.13 as well.

I think this has something to do clock setting, I tried setting up ntp and chrony as well. It passed once but it is still failing

**However these tests are passing with with sudo permissions**

```
sudo ./poll02 -> PASS 
./poll02 -> FAIL
```

Can anyone tell why this test passes with sudo syscall and fails with non-sudo user? How to make this test pass

The test isn't supposed to run with sudo. If root is required then in the end needs_root=true will be specified

https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/testcases/kernel/syscalls/poll/poll02.c

Answer (score 0):

Project's README says:

> Note that many test cases have to be executed as root.

These tests fail without `sudo` because they are designed to be run as root.

Comment: This testcase is not supposed to run as root

This is the default setup for the poll02 test. If root is required then they would mention .needs_root=true as part of below configuration

    static struct tst_test test = {
    .scall = "poll()",
    .sample = sample_fn,
    .setup = setup,
 .cleanup = cleanup,
        }

Comment: Any updates or any suggestions

Comment: @anjalirai Sorry, I've dug into this a bit but didn't come up with anything helpful.